# Should we merge the tags object-recognition and image-classification?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

From my experience, the terms/expressions "object recognition" or "object classification" are synonyms for "image classification" (also known as "image recognition").

Should we make "object recognition" (and "object classification") a synonym for "image classification"?

I think so, but, after a quick look at some of the [questions tagged with "object recognition"](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/object-recognition), it seems that some people used this latter tag also for questions that involved the task of "object detection", which is a different task. So, either I am wrong that these are synonymous (I don't think I am wrong), or, before merging these tags, we should probably revisit these posts and remove the unnecessary tags.